# Reading all frames in a video without using too much memory

Tags: java, video

I'm doing a project using Java and I need to read every frame from a video to perform some calculations. My first idea has been using some library to get all the frames and add them to some collection but I think that approach would take too much memory.

Since I have to read them only once, could I "free" the memory that each frame takes after using it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `{ Frame frame = new Frame(); frame.doAnalysis;} ` just let it fall out of scope

Comment: Thanks for answering, the question could look too obvious but I wanted to be sure. Any suggestions about a library to do this? I'm trying with Jcodec but I'm having troubles even with the sample code?